# jQuery Append removing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I try to use the jQuery Append method but its removing tags (tr, td) of my html code which I want to append. Why is it removing these and how can i force this method just to append and not to analyse my code?

Here is an example file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function () {
var htmlAppend = '';
htmlAppend = htmlAppend + '<input type="hidden" name="content0" value="' + 'hiddenvalues' + '"/>' + '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + 'content1' + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 'content2' + '</td>' + 
    '<td>' + 'content3' + '</td>' + 
    '<td><input style="width: 300px" type="text" name="content4"/></td>' +
'</tr>';                   
$("#ScenarioCompetenceRatings").append(htmlAppend);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button1">Add Row</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th style="width: 300px">Column4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ScenarioCompetenceRatings">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind and tell me where? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating invalid markup. You should put the hidden `input` element in a `td` element. `tbody` element can only have `tr` children.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to build? check on the fiddle i have created 
http://jsfiddle.net/FWkd2/`enter code here`
to check my fiddle